# Array of nested structures

Tags: c, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have huge arrays of nested structures which makes it impossible to allot that kind of space and forces me to use heap. But I am facing  difficulties using `malloc`.
The gist of the problem is below.

```
struct year_of_joining
{
    struct district
    {
        struct colleges
        {
            struct departments
            {
                struct sections
                {
                    struct students
                    {
                        int sex;
                    }student[100];
                }section_no[8];
            }department_no[17];
        }college[153];
    }dist[13];
};
```

If I use

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;    
    struct year_of_joining** year;
    year = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct year_of_joining));
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        year[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct year_of_joining));
    }

    year[1]->dist[0].college[0].department_no[0].section_no[0].student[8].sex = 1;//works fine
    printf("%d", year[1]->dist[0].college[0].department_no[0].section_no[0].student[8].sex);//prints 1
    free(year);
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine but when I create a pointer to pointer for dist like year_of_joining and use indirection operator it does not compile:

```
year[1]->dist[2]->college[0].department_no[0].section_no[0].student[8].sex = 9;//error C2039: 'dist' : is not a member of 'year_of_joining'
```

How do I solve this? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Your `struct` declaration does not create nested structs. It simply declares a bunch of struct types inside each other. Declaring a type inside `struct` without creating a named data field is illegal in C - the declaration will not even compile. Please, provide a more meaningful declaration. What exactly is nested and what are the nested data field names?

Comment: How can `D` have size 120? It is a pointer and two ints. And structs A, B and C are empty, so their size should be quite small.

Comment: @juanchopanza 120 is size of the array for structure D.

Comment: those sizes don't match the sizes of your arrays. You're off by one.

Comment: Moreover you have a leak: You assign the space for 13 As to create them another time in the for loop. Just do `struct A* ptr_A = calloc(13, sizeof(struct A));` and remove the for loop.

Comment: Another tipp: To avoid writing `struct A` all the time do `typedef struct {...} A;`

Comment: Looks like nightmare.

Comment: How can i improve this ?

Comment: @solinvictus Maybe you can use multiple small struct, and allocate memory dynamically, via malloc() famaily functions. Improve the design & organization of code.

Comment: @EricWang this structure actually looks the smallest, ideas on dividing further ?

Comment: You should provide more info about the data you are modelling if you want an answer to that.  Like, can a student be in two different departments, or what?

Comment: Sure.No student can be in two different departments.

Comment: That still isn't a complete specification of what data you are modelling and how it fits together, but I suppose we can just make some educated guesses.  I have updated my answer with my guess of a good data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are way off track here.

Note that a single `struct year_of_joining` is approximately 100 MiB of data.  An array of 100 such structures requires approximately 10 GiB of data (and that is only recording the sex of the students — no other information at all).

```
struct year_of_joining** year;
year = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct year_of_joining));
```

This memory allocation allocates enough space for millions of pointers.  You almost certainly intended to use:

```
struct year_of_joining *year = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct year_of_joining));

struct year_of_joining *year = malloc(100 * sizeof(*year));
```

This allocates 100 years worth of the structure.

However, it seems improbable that you have 13 districts, each of which has exactly 153 colleges, each college having exactly 17 departments, each of which has 8 sections, with each section having exactly 100 students.  That corresponds to over 25 million students every year!

You are going to need a vastly more flexible arrangement, where each of the structures contains a pointer to a list of the nested structures, so you can have bigger sections but smaller colleges, etc.  It will need to work more along the lines of:

```
struct students
{
    char name[32];
    int sex;
    // ... and other data ...
};

struct sections
{
    char name[32];
    // ... and other data ...
    int n_students;
    struct students *students;
};

struct departments
{
    char name[32];
    int n_sections;
    struct sections *sections;
}

struct colleges
{
    char name[32];
    // ... and other data ...
    int n_departments;
    struct departments *departments;
};

struct district
{
    char name[32];
    // ... and other data ..
    int n_colleges;
    struct college *colleges;
};

struct year_of_joining
{
    int  year;
    // ... and other data ...
    int  n_districts;
    struct district *districts;
};
```

Even that feels not entirely correct, but it would be a better way of organizing the data than the original, if only because if a department only has one section and enrolls only ten students (because it is a minority-interest department), then it allocates only enough space for one section and ten students, rather than allocating space for 800 students and 8 sections.

Comment: It depends on what you want.  You can have: `struct year_of_joining *yoj = malloc(sizeof(*yoj));` and now access the year (but you'd need to initialize it).  You can then add districts to this (more allocations and initializations).  And so on.  Without clearer specification of what else you want to do, it isn't possible to say how you access it.  Are you pulling data from a database?  How were you planning to record that the engineering department has 10 sections with more than 100 students in each, but the Amazonian Languages department has just 1 section with 4 students in total?  Etc.

Comment: I am getting data from a file for specified students.100 years 150 colleges is not at all applicable in my case i just got carried away.

Comment: Without knowing a lot more about how your data is organized, it is not really possible to say how to help you.  Please ask a new question, explaining where the data is stored and the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are not on the right track.  Your struct is really huge, and you will need to recompile your program if the size of your input (e.g. number of students) ever gets too big.

I suggest you model your data as smaller structs that can be individually allocated, perhaps using pointers or ID numbers to link them together.

Another language like Ruby might be a better choice than C, allowing you to focus more on your data than on the details of its storage in memory.  In general, C is good for fast, low-level interactions with the operating system, while languages with garbage compilers and dynamic typing will be much easier for writing reports and aggregating data.

Anyway, suppose you want to use C.  The data structure you choose will depend on several things.  What is the precise real-world structure of the data you are modelling?  What performance characteristics do you need?  Does it need to be fast to add things, or fast to extract certain statistics from the data?  Without knowing that answers to these questions, it is hard for us to come up with a usable answer for your application.  But Jonathan Leffler has taken a  good guess.  Here is my guess:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct student
{
  char * name;
  uint32_t sex;
  uint32_t year_of_joining;

  // Index into an array of sections.
  // You could also use a pointer to a section (section *)
  // but the pointer would become invalid if you ever moved the
  // sections in memory (e.g. by calling realloc on an array
  // of sections).
  uint32_t section_id;
};

struct section
{
  char * name;
  uint32_t department_id;
};

struct department
{
  char * name;
  uint32_t college_id;
};

struct college
{
  char * name;
  uint32_t district_id;
};

struct district
{
  char * name;
};

// These typedefs make it so we don't have to
// write "struct" when using the structs.
typedef struct student student;
typedef struct section section;
typedef struct department department;
typedef struct college college;
typedef struct district district;

// Dynamically sized arrays for holding things.
student * student_array;
section * section_array;
department * department_array;
college * college_array;
district * district_array;
```